# Sum of a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I have to find the sum of this series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$

Using integral, I got
$$\int\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n\cdot n!}$$

I know that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}=e^{x}$$

But my problem is about this $n\cdot n!$. How can I solve it?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is closely related to $e^x-1$. Write down the series for this, and the answer will pop out. The integration will turn out to be unnecessary.

Comment: Try something simpler than integration (like adding 1 and/or multiplying by $x$).

Comment: By the way, your last sum is $e^x-1$, not $e^x$ (since you started the sum at $n=1$). Divide through by $x$ (and also state what your first sum is when $x=0$) ...

Comment: just multiply and divide the first function by x ! Indeed for $x\neq0$ :
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}=\frac1x\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac1x(e^x-1)$$

Comment: Thank you all :D I didn't know I could multiply or divide by $x$ or  another thing.

Comment: @mvfs314 Just as long as whatever you're multiplying or dividing doesn't have an $n$ in it.  Then it's just basically the distributive property.